# link to pdf.js on website doesn't work - file not found

Tags: javascript, pdf, github, pdf.js

I want to use pdf.js for my website for displaying pdf files. This is the wikipage: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website

I have a website folder with index.html, the folder web and build from the pdf.js plugin and an assets map.

Now I want to open a PDF from my website with PDF.js. I used the example from the wiki:

```
<a href="/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fyourpdf.pdf">Open yourpdf.pdf with PDF.js</a>
```

I put a pdf with the name "yourpdf.pdf" in my folder, but it didn't work. Is the wiki incomplete or what goes wrong?

Comment: There are few steps before including link to your file. Make sure you followed them and try to carefully read the documentation. Most of the problems are because we miss something in documentation.

Comment: Referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website), I think you misplaced the directories.

It says you should move `pdf.js-gh-pages/build/`  `pdf.js-gh-pages/web/`. While you seem to have moved only web and build folder.

Comment: Yes I tried both, I placed a map called pdf.js-gh-pages which have 2 folders, build and web. That didn't worked, and the same for only the web and build folder.

Comment: What's the output ? Are you getting any error message in console ?

Comment: Just an object not found mention, 404 error

Comment: Care to mention actual error message here ?